# How to understand jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, bjqs

Using the logic from here: [Custom Link Trigger for Previous/Next Slide in Basic jQuery Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222889/custom-link-trigger-for-previous-next-slide-in-basic-jquery-slider)

I have made thumbnails for Basic jQuery Slider, here: http://www.venusadventures.travel/slidertest.html

My first choice was to try to access the bjqs methods directly, but not knowing how jquery plugins work, (or a whole lot about js) this didnt work :)

```
//my addition 
$('.thumb3').click(function(){
    path-to.go(false,3); //scope problems!!!
});

//bjqs snippits
$.fn.bjqs = function(o) {    
    ...
    var conf_markers = function() {
       // for every slide, create a marker
       $.each($slides, function(key, slide){

       // bind the click event
       marker.on('click','a',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       if(!state.animating && state.currentslide !== gotoslide) go(false,gotoslide); //HOW TO ACCESS go()?
    });
    ...
    var go = function(direction, position) {
        if(!state.animating){
        state.animating = true;
        if(position){
            state.nextslide = position;
            state.nextindex = position-1;
        }
        else{
            set_next(direction);
        }
        // fade animation
        ...
        }
    };
```

But now i realise i need to also catch the slide change event to update my active thumbnail, si need to go back toplan A. While i could modify bjqs, that would make non-upgradable. I just need a hint about the required scope to understand how to interact with the plugin methods directly. Cheers.

Edit: Cludge that works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#slider').bjqs({
        width : 620,
        height : 310,
        automatic : false,
        animtype : 'slide'
    });

    //hide bjqs plain blob markers
    $('ol.bjqs-markers').hide();

    //add thumbnail click handlers
    $('div.thumbcontrol img').each( function(t,tobj) {
        $('ol.bjqs-markers li a').each( function (m,mobj) {
            if (t==m) {
                $(tobj).click(function() {
                    $(mobj).trigger('click');
                    $('div.thumbcontrol img').removeClass('active');
                    $(tobj).addClass('active');
                });
            }
        });
    });

    //add click handlers to prev/next
    $('ul.bjqs-controls a').click( function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            //find the active native bjqs marker (after sliders own handler completes)
            var m= $('ol.bjqs-markers li.active-marker a').text() - 1;
            $('div.thumbcontrol img').each( function(t,tobj) {
                if (m==t) {
                    $('div.thumbcontrol img').removeClass('active');
                    $(tobj).addClass('active');
                }
            });
        },50)
     });
});
```

Comment: you can't call the `go` method directly because it is a local scoped function created inside a closure

Comment: i suspected as much, ta!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was maybe the plugin exposed a callback for after clicking prev/next. It appears that [it doesn't](http://www.basic-slider.com/). If nothing else, you can attach events to the DOM nodes that the plugin creates:

```
//attach events to prev/next handles
$('.bjqs-prev').click(function() {
    alert('clicked prev');
});
$('.bjqs-next').click(function() {
    alert('clicked next');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/7E6xe/

This should be sufficient unless there's something else that can trigger the prev/next behavior.

Comment: I guess thats all you can do. Thanks. If anyone trys this youll have to watch out for the fact that the native slider prev/next events only fire if the animation was complete, thus advancing the active slide this way wont actually work. thus this additional event will need to check the state of the native slide markers. The problem there becomes the sequence the events fire, and getting the true active marker. Thanks again.

Comment: And, of course it serves me right for not choosing a more capable slider to use in the first place. However this one is already widely used in our codebase. Thems the breaks.